# Using embedded frameworks for third party distribution of libraries

Tags: frameworks, ios8

Now that we have Cocoa touch libraries in iOS 8, is anyone thinking of packaging their third party libraries as Frameworks instead of static archives?

What are the pros/cons?  Technical and non technical are appreciated.